# Expanding a series with a constant

Tags: summation

How do you expand the series:

The sum, starting at j=1 and ending at 6 when the value next to the summation symbol on the right is 4?

Are all of the terms of the series 4?

Comment: do you mean $\sum_{j=1}^{6} 4$?

Comment: All the terms will be 4, and there will be 6 terms to add.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{j=1}^{6} 4=4+4+4+4+4+4=24$$